# maximum open cursors exceeded exception in java and oracle

Tags: java, oracle, performance, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I having problem with my code:
ERROR: ORA-01000: maximum open cursor exceeded. This code is called from multiple threads.
Q. is oracle cursors are differen than JDBC cursor(resultset)?

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con, String TBName)
        throws SQLException {

        Statement stmt = null;
        String query =   "select *from " + TBName;

        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String studentName = rs.getString("STD_NAME");

                System.out.println(studentName + "\t");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using thin or thick jdbc client? Please post the version as well. Also make sure you release/close all jdbc db related object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use try-with-resources to ensure that both statement and result set are closed.

```
    String query =   "select STD_NAME from " + TBName;
    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            String studentName = rs.getString("STD_NAME");
            System.out.println(studentName + "\t");
        }
    } // Closes rs and stmt even with exceptions.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should *always* close the ResultSet and the Statement. As you said, your code is accessed by many thread so a lot of Resultset will be open and never 
closed.

Put the ResultSet variable out of the try catch block and close it in a finally, beside the Statement closing.